# I want 'None' for Visual Effects but they keep reverting back

Tags: compiz

Ubuntu 10.04 64bit on a Dell Latitude E6400 laptop.

I want "None" under Visual Effects (on the Appearance Preferences), but when I reboot it reverts to Normal.  I've tried uninstalling Compiz but that clearly upsets the gods because then I lose my title bars. Googling for help on this produces answers involving the Visual Effects option, which is all ghosted out once I've uninstall compiz.  Not only that, but the keyboard is ignored in all windows unless only one window is open (actually, it might be just the window the mouse is currently over).  So if I google for help and the answer it is to type something into Terminal, I cannot do this until I quit the browser.

I installed another instance of Ubuntu from the same CD, which is working fine.

It seems to me that something else is perhaps trying to load/use compiz it when I reboot, and if it's not there it has this title bar problem.  There's nothing obvious in my "Startup Applications" list.

Edit:  I just created another user, and for this user the desired setting sticks, suggesting it's a per-user setting/problem, not a system wide one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiz Fusion Icon may be helpful.

Take a look at this: [Emerald window decorator fails to start... sometimes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27461/emerald-window-decorator-fails-to-start-sometimes/27468#27468), posted here for your convenience.

> You can use Compiz Fusion Icon which
>   can be easily installed by dropping
>   `sudo apt-get install fusion-icon` in
>   a terminal. After that, find the
>   fusion-icon in the System Tools menu
>   and you will have several choices in
>   the panel's fusion icon, which
>   includes but not limits to: *Select
>   Window Decorator*.
>
> Right click the fusion icon and choose
>   your prefered window decorator, window
>   manager and a few other features. Then
>   select "Reload Window Manager" and
>   your monitor or windows may flicker.
>
> Don't worry, it will take just a
>   moment to reload your options and
>   after that you can close the fusion
>   Icon. The options should persist this
>   time.
>
> A screenshot is placed here to
>   illustrate.
>
> Good luck!

[image]

### Edit

Take a look at this: http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Compiz-Fusion

If you are using Gnome, go to the Gnome's section, which is placed here for your convenience.
[image]

With this logic in mind, just

> To change the default window manager
>   in gnome run gconf-editor, and set
>   /desktop/gnome/session/required_components/windowmanager
>   to "metacity"

The majority of the times, running `metacity --replace` is enough for the changes you wish, but if needed, run `sudo metacity --replace` and let's see what happens.

I hope this help.

Comment: Yeah, by doing and and sort of playing around I've got the windows minimizing/maximizing quickly, even if I can't actually select "none".  I have to load that icon at each boot time, however, otherwise I can't alt-tab, ctrl-alt-left etc.    I can't just revert back to whatever "window manager" I was using before I experimented with Compiz?   Or is that Metacity?  In which case why have I lost the shortcuts?  There's nothing in the short-cut editor which tells me they're going to be ignored!

Comment: I edited my answer in order to give you a suggestion, I can't say why this happened to your system but I hope you find a solution.

Comment: No, that's been great.  What I learned from it was that you have to use fusion to "reload window manager" (without actually selecting a different one) then I can alt-tab etc. Or typing "metacity --replace" does the same thing, so I simply added that to my "startup applications" list and it's done the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>
2. Type: `metacity --replace` (It will give compiz the blue pill)
3. Go to System -> Preferences-> Appearance
4. Go to Visual Effects tab and Select NONE.

The problem you have i sometimes have it if at the moment of changing to NONE am still using Compiz. Does not happen every time but when it does it happens exactly as you described.

Let me know if it helps since this is a most have answer for me and several students i have that want to join the Linux world.

Comment: Nope.  I have to have compiz enabled to attempt the above, but when I reboot it's back to "normal" and not "none".